# Access the underlying (tree_) object of a single tree in a Random-Forest model (Python, scikit-learn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I need to convert a Random Fores model to a rule-based model or (if-then) based model. I have now created my model and it is well tuned. The problem I face is that I cannot "access" the (base_estimator) or the underlying (tree_ object) which will make it possible create a function that can extract the rules from the trees in the forest. I would be very thankful if You can help me with this issue. To create the model I use:

```
    estimator = RandomForestRegressor(oob_score=True, n_estimators=10,max_features='auto')
```

I tried to use the `estimator.estimators_` attribute to access a single tree and then use for example `estimator.estimators_[0].tree_`to get the decision tree (`DecisionTreeRegressor` object) used to build the forest. Unfortunately, this method does not work.

If possible, I want something like:

```
   estimator = RandomForestRegressor(oob_score=True, n_estimators=10,max_features='auto')
   estimator.fit(tarning_data,traning_target)
   tree1 = estimator.estimators_[0]
   leftChild = tree1.tree_.children_left
   rightChild = tree1.tree_.children_right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the underlying structure of a `DecisionTreeRegressor` object in a Random-forest model, you need to follow the steps described below:

```
estimator = RandomForestRegressor(oob_score=True,n_estimators=10,max_features='auto')
estimator.fit(tarning_data,traning_target)
tree1 = estimator.estimators_[0]
leftChilds = tree1.tree_.children_left # array of left children
rightChilds = tree1.tree_.children_right #array of right children
```

i.e. essentially what is already described in the question.